# How is it possible to export FilterTable to Excel

Tags: vaadin, export-to-excel

How is it possible to export FilterTable to Excel? There is a tool "TableExport", but it can be used only for the ordinary table. In my case, there is a FilterTable.. how I can export it?

Comment: I think it should also work with the FilterTable, you perhaps have to access the underlying vaadin Table and pass that one to the excel export.

Comment: how to do it? ExcelExport excelExport = new ExcelExport (myTable). How I can pass filterTable there?

Comment: Ahh.. the patch has not made it into the export component. https://code.google.com/p/tableexport-for-vaadin/source/detail?r=09d842762bafc6fbc055509c4b4f91500341fcf5

Comment: Or if it's really burning and you can't wait until the patch gets propagated, you can write your own implementation using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a CustomTableHolder and ExcelExport:

```
final CustomTableHolder holder = new CustomTableHolder(my_filter_table);
final ExcelExport excelExport = new ExcelExport(holder);
excelExport.export();
```

Usually best to add that to a clickevent on a button.

Both the CustomTableHolder and ExcelExport has several options that you could tweak.